How to manage multiple python virtual environments in a single VS Code project?
I'm working on a Python project in Visual Studio Code that consists of two separate sections, each with its own virtual environment. One environment is for my REST API, and the other section is for my Amazon CDK deployment. I'm having trouble managing these environments so that the correct interpreter is used for each section.
How can I configure VS Code to correctly use the specified interpreter for each section of my project without having to manually switch environments each time?
Is there a better way to manage multiple virtual environments in a single project in VS Code?
How can I properly set the interpreter for WSL in VS Code to avoid the invalid interpreter error?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
When I switch between the two sections in VS Code, the imports in one section fail after I select the interpreter for the other section. It seems like VS Code is not properly switching between the virtual environments for each section. Additionally, I encountered the following error when trying to use WSL:

An Invalid Python interpreter is selected, please try changing it to
enable features such as IntelliSense, linting and debugging. See
output for more details regarding why the interpreter is invalid.

I have created separate virtual environments for each section and specified the paths to the respective interpreters in each .vscode/settings.json file.

if you have multiple virtual environments in a project, you can use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P to open the command panel. Inputting Select Interpreter and it will list the available interpreters. Then you can select any of them and then create a new terminal. The selected virtual environment will be activated. Or use the command in the terminal to change it. It's like the picture.
